# Perfect Solution For Skin and Hair

Tags: dermatology, lifestyle, hair, hairloss, oil-of-skin

i am planing to make routine that help to improve hair and skin health  .

I have **Aleo Vera , curd , Fenugreek Seeds , Egg** etc . And i hear that all these are very good for hair and skin . Now what my doubt is how can i apply these ,things? First day i can apply aleo vera, then second day etc etc  ??

If anyone use these please suggest good routine .

Thank you

Comment: I think the way you plan your routine is highly dependent on your skin type as well as your hair type. For me, I have mixed skin type, between  oily skin and dry skin ( even it depends on the weather) , I used to  have  a mask of almond oil + castor oil , I do it once every two weeks, and  the results appears nice to me. you can also use coconut oil for moisturizing your hair. This is just a suggestion, it is not an answer.  I think the perfect way is to do your own routine according to you skin needs, type, and availability. ( PS: take care to buy these products from the pharmacy)